# A smart pointer maker

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I'm working on the classical example of perfect forwarding : the smart pointers maker.

```
template<typename T>
   //Return a smart pointer on the given objet
   shared_ptr<T> smartPointerMaker(T&& arg)
   {
       return shared_ptr<T>(forward<T>(arg));
   }

//In the main...
shared_ptr<int> p = smartPointerMaker(42);
```

But it doesn't compile, saying that "no matching function for call to 'std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(int)'"

Comment: You should be using `T&&` for forwarding and an elipsis `...` for variadic templates.

Comment: Where did you get this example? There doesn't seem to be anything "classical" about it.

Comment: Now you are missing the `new T` part of the creation. Right now you are trying to create a `std::shared_ptr<int>` by giving it an int as an argument, which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [`std::make_shared()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) if it is available in your compiler (which it should):

```
shared_ptr<int> p = make_shared<int>(42);
```

Your manual implementation does not work because you are not passing the input argument to a `new`'ed instance of `T` for the `shared_ptr` to hold. You are trying to pass the argument to the `shared_ptr` constructor directly, which is not how `shared_ptr` works, and why the code fails to compile.

You need to forward the argument to the `T` constructor, and pass a `new`ed instance pointer of `T` to the `shared_ptr` constructor, eg:

```
template<class T, class U>
shared_ptr<T> smartPointerMaker(U&& arg)
{
    return shared_ptr<T>(new T(forward<U>(arg)));
}
```

Or:

```
template<class T, class... U>
shared_ptr<T> smartPointerMaker(U&&... args)
{
    return shared_ptr<T>(new T(forward<U>(args)...));
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
shared_ptr<int> p = smartPointerMaker<int>(42);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've written your perfect forwarding function correctly, so that it forwards its arguments, then

```
shared_ptr<int> p = smartPointerMaker(42);
```

is equivalent to:

```
shared_ptr<int> p = shared_ptr<int>(42);
```

It should not be surprising that this doesn't compile.